How do I scroll one page at a time while viewing two pages in Evince?
When viewing a document one page at a time in Evince, there are several key pairings that allow me to scroll, like Up and Down, Left and Right, etc. When in double view (two pages at a time), these keys scroll understandably scroll two pages at a time. My question is, how can I scroll one page a time while in double view? For example, if I'm viewing pages 1-2, and I press Down, I move to pages 3-4: how can I move to pages 2-3?
